# Clone and run laravel application easily

Tags: php, laravel, docker, docker-compose, laradock

I have developed my first laravel web app application on my local machine. Which is the best way to clone and run locally this web application on other computers by other people? I want to share this application and simplify the "clone" and "run" processes. Maybe docker or laradock?

I want to avoid PHP, Apache and Mysql installation on other machines. My main goal is clone the repository and run it in other computer easily.

Could you provide the best tools or ways to do that?

Answer (score 1):

There is laravel valet https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/valet but it's only for mac environment. They say it's the fastest way.

Comment: There is also a valet version for windows 
https://github.com/cretueusebiu/valet-windows
and linux https://github.com/cpriego/valet-linux